# Windows 7 Login Screen

Tags: windows-7, login

In a network install of Windows 7, is there a way to get back to the old style of username, password and Domain input? I don't like how if you want another user to login they have to click 2 buttons to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. For Windows 7/Vista, the user does not have a drop-down listbox for selection of the Domain or Local PC, and there is no way at all to get it back. The user has to manually type in COMPUTERNAME\username. Do the Ctrl + Alt + Del then click on Switch User button. Select the blank OTHER USER and you will have the classic login screen so you can then use:

   DOMAIN\USER NAME
   PASSWORD
2. Look thru Control Panel / System & Security / Administrative Tools / Local Security Policy -> Local Policies\Security Options\ . Maybe, there's something useful, like '**Do not display last user name**'? Run `gpupdate.exe` to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but please update this if you find a way. Would be nice to have handy.

Comment: Yeah, everything I'm looking at is how to change it TO the new crap way...

Comment: +1 for crap :) [pad][pad][pad][pad]

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.